# Unable to create an .war in Cuba.Platform

Tags: eclipse, gradle, web-deployment, gradlew, cuba-platform

I did this tutorial of Cuba.Platform: https://github.com/aleksey-stukalov/workshop/wiki

and developed this project in the Eclipse IDE.

Now, I want to deploy the project and I use this link to do it: (using gradle)

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-latest/tomcat_war_deployment.html

But, when I write `gradlew buildWar` in the `cmd` command, I get the following problem:

**gredlew buildWar fail :/** [image]

EDIT:

when I write in cmd: `gredlew buildWar --stacktrace`
I get this output:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.file.UnableToDeleteFileException: Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\ersterTest\build\distributions\war
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.delete.Deleter.handleFailedDelete(Deleter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.delete.Deleter.doDeleteInternal(Deleter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.delete.Deleter.delete(Deleter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.delete.Deleter.delete(Deleter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.delete(DefaultFileOperations.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.delete(DefaultProject.java:790)
    at CubaWarBuilding.init(CubaWarBuilding.groovy:298)
    at CubaWarBuilding.build(CubaWarBuilding.groovy:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    … 70 more

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.15 secs
```

and this is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.cubaVersion = '6.7.3'
    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://repo.cuba-platform.com/content/groups/work'
            credentials {
                username(rootProject.hasProperty('repoUser') ? rootProject['repoUser'] : 'cuba')
                password(rootProject.hasProperty('repoPass') ? rootProject['repoPass'] : 'cuba123')
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.haulmont.gradle:cuba-plugin:$cubaVersion"
    }
}

def globalModule = project(':app-global')
def coreModule = project(':app-core')
def guiModule = project(':app-gui')
def webModule = project(':app-web')

def servletApi = 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:8.0.26'
apply(plugin: 'idea')
apply(plugin: 'cuba')

cuba {
    artifact {
        group = 'com.company.erstertest'
        version = '0.1'
        isSnapshot = true
    }
    tomcat {
        dir = "$project.rootDir/deploy/tomcat"
    }
}

dependencies {
    appComponent("com.haulmont.cuba:cuba-global:$cubaVersion")

}

def hsql = 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.2.9'

configure([globalModule, coreModule, guiModule, webModule]) {
    apply(plugin: 'java')
    apply(plugin: 'maven')
apply(plugin: 'idea')
apply(plugin: 'cuba')

    dependencies {
        testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    }

    task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
        from file('src')
        classifier = 'sources'
    }

    artifacts {
        archives sourceJar
    }
}

configure(globalModule) {
    task enhance(type: CubaEnhancing)


}

configure(coreModule) {

    configurations {
        jdbc
        dbscripts
    }

    dependencies {
        compile(globalModule)
        provided(servletApi)
        jdbc(hsql)
        testRuntime(hsql)

    }

    task cleanConf(description: 'Cleans up conf directory') {
        doLast {
            def dir = new File(cuba.tomcat.dir, '/conf/app-core')
            if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                ant.delete(includeemptydirs: true) {
                    fileset(dir: dir, includes: '**/*', excludes: 'local.app.properties')
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task deploy(dependsOn: [assemble, cleanConf], type: CubaDeployment) {
        appName = 'app-core'
        appJars('app-global', 'app-core')
    }

    task createDb(dependsOn: assembleDbScripts, description: 'Creates local database', type: CubaDbCreation) {
        dbms = 'hsql'
        host = 'localhost'
        dbName = 'erstertest'
        dbUser = 'sa'
        dbPassword = ''
    }

    task updateDb(dependsOn: assembleDbScripts, description: 'Updates local database', type: CubaDbUpdate) {
        dbms = 'hsql'
        host = 'localhost'
        dbName = 'erstertest'
        dbUser = 'sa'
        dbPassword = ''
    }
}

configure(guiModule) {
    dependencies {
        compile(globalModule)

    }

    task deployConf(type: Copy) {
        from file('src')
        include "com/company/erstertest/**"
        into "$cuba.tomcat.dir/conf/app"
    }
}

configure(webModule) {
    configurations {
        webcontent
    }

    dependencies {
        provided(servletApi)
        compile(guiModule)

    }

    task webArchive(type: Zip) {
        from file("$buildDir/web")
        from file('web')
        classifier = 'web'
    }

    artifacts {
        archives webArchive
    }

    task deployConf(type: Copy) {
        from file('src')
        include "com/company/erstertest/**"
        into "$cuba.tomcat.dir/conf/app"
    }

    task clearMessagesCache(type: CubaClearMessagesCache) {
        appName = 'app'
    }
    deployConf.dependsOn clearMessagesCache

    task cleanConf(description: 'Cleans up conf directory') {
        doLast {
            def dir = new File(cuba.tomcat.dir, '/conf/app')
            if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                ant.delete(includeemptydirs: true) {
                    fileset(dir: dir, includes: '**/*', excludes: 'local.app.properties')
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task deploy(dependsOn: [assemble, cleanConf], type: CubaDeployment) {
        appName = 'app'
        appJars('app-global', 'app-gui', 'app-web')
    }
}





task undeploy(type: Delete, dependsOn: ':app-web:cleanConf') {
    delete("$cuba.tomcat.dir/shared")
    delete("$cuba.tomcat.dir/webapps/app-core")
    delete("$cuba.tomcat.dir/webapps/app")
}

task restart(dependsOn: ['stop', ':app-core:deploy', ':app-web:deploy'], description: 'Redeploys applications and restarts local Tomcat') {
    doLast {
        ant.waitfor(maxwait: 6, maxwaitunit: 'second', checkevery: 2, checkeveryunit: 'second') {
            not {
                socket(server: 'localhost', port: '8787')
            }
        }
        start.execute()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.4'
}

task buildWar(type: CubaWarBuilding) {
    appHome = './app_home'
    singleWar = false
    includeContextXml = true
    includeJdbcDriver = true
    appProperties = ['cuba.automaticDatabaseUpdate': true]
}

apply from: 'extra.gradle'
```

Comment: Hm, can you try to manually delete `C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\ersterTest\build\distributions\war` and see if this fixes the error? Maybe you run the build with administrative rights before and now you try to run it as normal user, missing the file permissions to delete that folder? Btw. you can replace `rootProject.hasProperty('repoUser') ? rootProject['repoUser'] : 'cuba'` by `rootProject.findProperty('repoUser') ?: 'cuba'`.